# Why isn't the capillary tube displaced downward by the column of water?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, capillary-action

Water moves upward in a capillary tube due to intermolecular forces between water and the glass wall of the capillary tube.

If those forces act on water **pushing it up**, why don't we see the opposite effect (water forcing the walls of the tube **down**, due to Newton's third law)?

I know this is not a paradox, I am just looking for the correct description as to why we don't see this effect.

Comment: The capillary tube is usually not just floating in the water. If it were its buoyant force would be affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do.  The walls of the tube are pulled down.  However, virtually
in all meaningful situations, the tube is sufficiently anchored such that this small force is undetectable.  It just gets transferred onto the ground/table/etc.

However, were you to do this experiment in zero-gravity, and expose an open tube to a drop of water, you would indeed see that the water moves one way, and the tube moves the other way.  The end result would be that the center of mass of the water/tube did not change.

Hypothetically, if you put the tube on some hyper-sensitive crush washer which was calibrated to crush *just* over the force the empty tube applies, you would find that adding water crushes the washer.  The water would be pulled up, and its mass would be supported by the tube, and thus supported by the washer.

Comment: Excellent answer, it will be accepted as soon as possible. Do you mind explaining your last paragraph though? What is this "crush washer" you mention? (not a native english speaker)

Comment: @RobertoValente They are a particular kind of washer used in sealing to keep out liquid.  They are designed to crush, deforming permanently, as you tighten the bolt onto them, forming a perfect seal with whatever surface they mate with.  Our vehicle came with one for the oil drain, which means every time we replaced the oil, we also had to buy a new crush washer.

Comment: Interesting, so in this scenario it would be used to seal the capillary tube, if I understand correctly? Also, what did you mean by "crushes the water"? Thanks.

Comment: @RobertoValente They'd usually be used to seal the tube, but in this case I just wanted to use them as a physical support -- something which can hold up the tube's weight, but then fails visibly, deforming under the additional weight of the tube plus water.  My effort to find a hypothetical example might simply have generated more confusion rather than less confusion!

Comment: I think I understand now! I believe you meant "crushes the **washer**" then, is that correct? You wrote it crushes the **water**. Thanks again!!

Comment: @RobertoValente Yes, that typo makes the sentence incredibly confusing!  I have fixed it.  Sorry for that!  I really do hate when typos actually change the meaning of sentences!